# Scrape text mixed with emojis with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape live chats from Youtube streaming. I can use rvest's html_text() to get the texts and I can also use html_attr("shared-tooltip-text") to get the emojis. For my data, I can then combine them by putting the emojis behind the text to create a text string. HOWEVER, I can't figure out how to get the text and emojis in the order they appear in the original message.

Here is a sample chat message below

```
<span id="message" dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer">

"text pt1"

<img class="small-emoji emoji yt-formatted-string style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer" src="https://www.youtube.com/s/gaming/emoji/0f0cae22/emoji_u1f49b.svg" alt="" shared-tooltip-text=":yellow_heart:" id="emoji-74"> 

"text pt2"

<img class="small-emoji emoji yt-formatted-string style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer" src="https://www.youtube.com/s/gaming/emoji/0f0cae22/emoji_u1f499.svg" alt="" shared-tooltip-text=":blue_heart:" id="emoji-75">

</span>
```

If I use

```
messages <- html_elements(chat_html,"#message")
texts <- html_text(messages)
```

I get

> "text pt1 text pt2"

I can then use
emoji <- html_attr(html_elements(messages,"img"),"shared-tooltip-text")
to get the emojis' names.

But the fact that the emojis are in between the text is not captured.

Is there a way to scrape and get

> "text pt 1 :yellow_heart: text pt 2 :blue_heart:"

Thank you very much! Sorry, I'm a complete amateur. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can use an xpath the selects both `text` and `img` nodes, and a custom `ifelse` function to extract the correct information and collapse it:

```r
library(rvest)

sample_html <- read_html('<span id="message" dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer"> text pt1 <img class="small-emoji emoji yt-formatted-string style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer" src="https://www.youtube.com/s/gaming/emoji/0f0cae22/emoji_u1f49b.svg" alt="" shared-tooltip-text=":yellow_heart:" id="emoji-74"> text pt2 <img class="small-emoji emoji yt-formatted-string style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer" src="https://www.youtube.com/s/gaming/emoji/0f0cae22/emoji_u1f499.svg" alt="" shared-tooltip-text=":blue_heart:" id="emoji-75"> </span>')

get_text <- function(x) {
  ifelse(html_name(x) == "text", html_text(x), html_attr(x, "shared-tooltip-text")) |>
    paste(collapse = " ")
}

sample_html |>
  html_elements(xpath = "//span[@id='message']//text() | //span[@id='message']//img[contains(@class, 'emoji')]") |>
  get_text()

#[1] [1] " text pt1  :yellow_heart:  text pt2  :blue_heart:"
```

Let me know if this works!

Edits upon further query:

```r
sample_html <- read_html('
<span id="message" dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer">
   "text 1"
   <img class="small-emoji emoji yt-formatted-string style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer" src="https://www.youtube.com/s/gaming/emoji/0f0cae22/emoji_u1f49b.svg" alt="" shared-tooltip-text=":yellow_heart:" id="emoji-74"> 
</span>

<span  id="message" dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer"> "text 2" </span>')

get_text <- function(x) {
  ifelse(html_name(x) == "text", html_text(x), html_attr(x, "alt")) |>
    paste(collapse = " ")
}

texts <- sample_html |>
  html_elements(xpath = "//span[@id='message']//text() | //span[@id='message']//img[contains(@class, 'emoji')]")

get_text(texts) %>%
  str_remove_all("\"|\\n") %>%
  str_trim() %>%
  str_squish()

#[1] "text 1 :yellow_heart: text 2"
```

It is not a list, there are just some things you have to get rid of this time for it to look like a proper string.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!

However, I did run into a new problem with the codes you provided. 

Say, I have multiple chat texts as follows:

Comment: Thank you very much! I left my new question as another answer. I can't figure out how to post long followup question in comment. Sorry.